# NoMethodError - undefined method for nil:NilClass:

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am Rails noob and I am trying to unsderstand this simple JSON parsing code from a tutorial. Why do I get the nil:NilClass Error? What is a NilClass?

Thanks!

```
    app.put '/users/update' do
    params = JSON.parse(request.body.read)

    reqUserID = params[:id]

    requestUser = Models::Persistence::User.find_by_id(reqUserID)

    content_type "application/json"
    puts "Hello"
    puts requestUser.username

    if (requestUser)
      status 401
      return
    end
```

Comment: your `requestUser` is `nil`.  Check there is data in the `model`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Null`, in Ruby is called `nil` and like everything else, `nil` is also an object. An object of [NilClass](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/NilClass.html).

You get this error if you try to call a method on a `nil` object.

So in this case, `requestUser` is probably `nil`